# How to add <documentation> node to Cache Web Service WSDL?

Tags: soap, wsdl, intersystems-cache

Need to add ... like this

```
<definitions>
    <documentation></documentation>
     <types></types>
    <message><message/>
</definitions>
```

I set the `INCLUDEDOCUMENTATION` parameter to 1, but that doesn't generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently only possible for complex types, not for [webmethods](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20111/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOP_serv_details#GSOP_serv_details_annotations):

This parameter does not cause the WSDL to include comments for the web service and its web methods; there is no option to automatically include these comments in the WSDL.

Other than that, INCLUDEDOCUMENTATION is the right parameter to change.
There is already an enhancement request filed with ISC regarding this.